# I can't send ajax request using XAMP

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, xampp

i'm using an ajax login which work perfectly on Wamp Server windows , but when i 've passed to Xamp on kali linux it doesn't work :

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: baseurl + 'index.php?login/ajax_login',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        username: $("input#username").val(),
                        password: $("input#password").val(),
                    },
                    error: function () {

                        alert("An error occoured!");
                    },
```

when i click on login button it shows :An error occoured!
i don't know where is the problem , cause the app work perfectly on wampserver.
i wish that you gonna help me.
for the frameworks i m using codeIgniter .

here it is the form:

```
 <form method="post" role="form" id="form_login">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="entypo-user"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="nom.prenom" autocomplete="off"  />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="entypo-key"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-login">
                            <i class="entypo-login"></i>
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>


                </form>
```

here it is the ajax_login.php:

```
 function ajax_login() {

    $response = array();

    //Recieving post input of email, password from ajax request

    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $response['submitted_data'] = $_POST;



    //Validating login

    $login_status = $this->validate_login($username, $password);

    $response['login_status'] = $login_status;

    if ($login_status == 'success') {

        $response['redirect_url'] = $this->session->userdata('last_page');
    }

    //Replying ajax request with validation response
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

it is a function within a controller named login ,and this is the baseurl:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/elit';
```

i am using codeIgniter framework

Comment: can you show me the html form plz

Comment: @Laith yes of Course :)

Comment: Can you replace `error: function....}` with `error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                },
`

Comment: This will shows us the error that is coming up. If you are in Chrome go to the developer console and copy any errors that have come up and edit your question.

Comment: Did you bother to read the error or...?

Comment: Me or @fodilleo

Comment: @Ricky it shows 404

Comment: Just 404? Can you maybe put the entire error into your question.

Comment: Request URL:  http://localhost/elit/index.php?login/ajax_login
Request Method:  POST
Status Code:  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: can you please give me the name of the page that you are sending the post data to ? or i mean the php code that will handle it , which page it is exist so i can add it to the answer

Comment: @fodilleo — 404 Not Found seems clear enough.

Comment: @Quentin the same app work perfectly on windows using Wampserver !!!!

Comment: mmmm i guess after seeing your php code , i have to edit  your php code to fit the code that i typed lol , you are validation the username and the password with data from a database ? @fodilleo

Comment: @Laith yeah from database

Comment: cool , give me few mins

Comment: @fodilleo — We can't tell what is different between the two deployments. All we can tell is that the URL is not found by the server. Maybe you forgot to upload a PHP file or something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok found few things that are missing in the HTML form code :

Edit : After reading Quentin comments and the information that he provided which is right i had to take the part where i said :

> First you did not include the action in the form tag , the action
>   means where this form data are going to be either submitted or
>   whatever the is going to happen on that form , where it going ?

The correct info is this :

> The action attribute is optional. If omitted, the form is submitted to
>   the current URL. That's irrelevant though since the form isn't being
>   submitted. JavaScript is reading the data from it and making the HTTP
>   request instead.  For correcting my information about the Action
>   attribute .

Thank you Quentin for the correct information .

I edited the Form code and the AJAX code with a new one but with few changes , this code works perfect for me on XAMP:

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form" id="form_login" onsubmit="return UserSignIn();">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="entypo-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="nom.prenom" autocomplete="off"  />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="entypo-key"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-login">
                        <i class="entypo-login"></i>
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The AJAX Code :

```
<script>
    function UserSignIn()
        {
            var username = document.getElementByI('username').value;
            var password = document.getElementByI('username').value;

            if(username && password )
            {
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '',
                data: {
                    username,
                    password
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    alert("Code Works");
                },
                    error: function(response){
                    console.log(response);  
                    }
                });
            }
        return false;
        }
</script>
```

Note : In this part `url: ''` plz put the target page that will receive the data from the AJAX code . For example , if the php page were in the same folder as the page that this form is in  ,just type that name page with , ex : `url: 'login.php'` , if login.php exisst in another folder lets assum that folder name was login you will do this : `url: 'login/login.php'` .

Now when you do what i asked you to do click on submit , if it show alert box that says " code works "!! thats mean the code works perfect and you are good to go and edit it with your needs , but if it did not , then we have to see your php code .

Hope that fix your issue , let me know if you need more explanation .

Comment: well i've done those changes but unfortunately the same problem , you should keep in mind that the app as it is work perfectly on WampServer so i think that i need some configuration only , thank you anyway ;)

Comment: yea it will not work cause now i have to edit the php code too lol do u mind if i edited all the php code ? the php code should take the parameters it selfs , and it will not be called by a function

Comment: @fodilleo im typing a php code and i will use PDO .

Comment: "First you did not include the action in the form tag , the action means where this form data are going to be either submitted or whatever the is going to happen on that form , where it going ?" — The action attribute is optional. If omitted, the form is submitted to the current URL. That's irrelevant though since the form isn't being submitted. JavaScript is reading the data from it and making the HTTP request instead.

Comment: "You forgot to call the Ajax function that will take all the form data" — The question says "it shows :An error occoured!", which is an error message you can see in the source code of the JavaScript. If the Ajax function wasn't being called then that wouldn't happen.

Comment: @Quentin yea you right but if you noticed that the Javascript form is being called as you can see here : `onsubmit="return UserSignIn();` . For the your second comment , yes you are right too , but the OP is not showing the error at all , so its hard to know is it from the AJAX or from the form it self , as for me , i always use this `error: function(response){ console.log(response);` to check if there is an error in the ajax code . Thank you for your comment . =)

Comment: @Laith — (1) There's no "but" about it. You're simply agreeing with me. The fact the OP didn't include the code which triggered the JS in their question and you did in your "answer" doesn't change the fact that their question cleared showed the JS was running in the first place. (2) "OP is not showing the error at all" — They aren't showing a *useful* error, but they are showing an error output by their own JavaScript so … "its hard to know is it from the AJAX or from the form it self" is just wrong. The error is from the JavaScript.

Comment: yes sir i agree with you , no doubt  , thank you for new info , i will edit the answer with that =) , accept my apology =)

Comment: @Quentin i have edited the answer and toke my wrong information and added yours , thank you again sir .

Comment: You don't appear to have addressed the problem (which is that the server is reporting a 404 for the URL despite the OP being convinced that the URL is correct and that it works on another server). The answer seems to be a *lot* of stuff that you say doesn't matter and the statement "plz put the target page that will receive the data from the AJAX code" … which the OP says they have already done.

Comment: Yea i edited the part that you explained to me so i don't give wrong information to the OP , As for the problem and the error , yea i did not exactly know where the problem exist , and another stupid thing happened , i was reading tow Q at the same time so a lot of info mixed up me , but even so i have to read his Code again to see where the issue in , my answer was a suggestion from me ,  Even so i will try to see the main problem and edit the answer again with main goal ( the problem and the solve ) if i found it .Thank you again .